# как соединить углы прямоугольников в CANVAS

Tags: javascript, canvas

есть 2 `input`(в `input` числа записываются через дефис на пример: `120-120`) и один `button` при нажатии на кнопку создаются прямоугольники и они должны соединиться вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не получается реализовать соединение, вот мой код:

```js
const canv = document.querySelector('canvas')
const tools = canv.getContext('2d')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  let in1 = inp1.value.split('-')
  tools.strokeRect(100, 100, in1[0], in1[1])
  let in2 = inp2.value.split('-')
  tools.strokeRect(150, 150, in2[0], in2[1])
})
```

```html
<input id="inp1" value="120-120">
<input id="inp2" value="150-150">
<button id="btn">add</button>
<br>
<br>
<canvas width="900" height="600" style="background: yellowgreen"></canvas>
```

Comment: В Вашем коде нет наклонных линий. Как Вы их делали?

Comment: @Igor , т.е. через strokeRect не правильно?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_strokerect.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const canv = document.querySelector('canvas')
const tools = canv.getContext('2d')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  let in1 = inp1.value.split('-')
  tools.strokeRect(100, 100, in1[0], in1[1])
  let in2 = inp2.value.split('-')
  tools.strokeRect(150, 150, in2[0], in2[1])
  
  tools.moveTo(100, 100);
  tools.lineTo(150, 150);

  tools.moveTo(100 + +in1[0], 100);
  tools.lineTo(150 + +in2[0], 150);

  tools.moveTo(100 + +in1[0], 100 + +in1[1]);
  tools.lineTo(150 + +in2[0], 150 + +in2[1]);

  tools.moveTo(100, 100 + +in1[1]);
  tools.lineTo(150, 150 + +in2[1]);

  tools.stroke();
})
```

```html
<input id="inp1" value="120-120">
<input id="inp2" value="200-200">
<button id="btn">add</button>
<br>
<br>
<canvas width="900" height="600" style="background: yellowgreen"></canvas>
```